# How to sent a message to all users in sockets io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Good morning
I would like in my chat send a message to all user when a user comes to connect to display a text
loginxxx is connected I found that but it's not working
I don't know where to put this code
Here all my code

```js
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
/*io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.join('room1');
  console.log('room créé');
  let msg="hi";
io.sockets.emit('sendMsgToAll',msg);
  });*/


io.sockets.on("connect", function(socket){// GESTIONNAIRE CONNECTION D'UN CLIENT 
// CREATION DE LA ROOM 


console.log("Un client s'est connecté");
socket.on("infoUser", function(userInfoUrl){ 
         // RECUPERE LES INFOS DE L'URL DE CHAT.HTML ET LES TRANSFORME EN JSON SECURISER LE SERVEUR DE SOCKET SINON PLANTAGE 
         // INSTAURER UNE SESSION POUR ETRE OBLIGE DE PASSER PAR CONNEXION !
         //http://localhost:3000/chat.html?pseudo=_Alicee_H1&age=25&ville=Bordeaux&sexe=femme
       let url = new URL(userInfoUrl);
       let pseudo = url.searchParams.get("pseudo");
       let age = url.searchParams.get("age");
       let ville = url.searchParams.get("ville");
       let sexe = url.searchParams.get("sexe");
       console.log(sexe);
       console.log(userInfoUrl+" id:"+socket.id);
       let userInfos='{"pseudo":"'+pseudo+'","age":"'+age+'","ville":"'+ville+'","sexe":"'+sexe+'"}';
       console.log(userInfos);
       userInfos=JSON.parse(userInfos);
       // AJOUTER JSON.parse
        //TRAITER DECONEXION
        // FAIRE CORESPONDRE PSEUDO ET SOCKET.ID        
        socket.emit('pseudo',userInfos['pseudo']);
        
       
});
io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.join('room1');
  console.log('room créé');
  let msg="hi";
io.sockets.emit('sendMsgToAll',msg);
  });
// A GERER LA DECONNEXION D'UN USER SPECIFIQUE VOIR TUTOS 
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
console.log('A user disconnected');
});



});
```

```js
io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.join('room1');
  console.log('room créé');
  let msg="hi";
io.sockets.emit('sendMsgToAll',msg);
  });
```

I don't where to put the code above with conection
I'am a newbie
What is the difference between connect  and connection?

Edit my script client side concerning Socket.io

```js
function pageIsLoaded(){
//var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");


var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");//CONNECTION AU SERVEUR 
// ON RECUPERE LES VALEURS DE L'URL 
socket.on('sendMsgToAll',function(msg){

alert(msg);


});
//alert(Cookies.get('pseudo'));
socket.emit("infoUser",location.href);//ENVOI AU SERVEUR 

//socket.emit("event1,"Bonjour");//ENVOI AU SERVEUR 
/*socket.on('pseudo', function(data){
document.body.querySelector("#room").innerHTML=data;
//document.getElementById("displaydata").innerHTML=data+"|"+Cookies.get('pseudo');

});*/
}
function addListener(element,baseName,Funct)

{

if(element.addEventListener){

   element.addEventListener(baseName,Funct,false)
   
   
   }

 else if (element.attachEvent){

          element.attachEvent('on'+baseName,Funct)}
          


}

window.addListener(window,'load',pageIsLoaded );
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Connect](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/#connect)

Comment: Could you label which code is server-side vs. client-side?

Comment: thanks for your anwser it's only the server side

Comment: The response is that I must use connect or connection events not the 2 both .In this case connection.